# "overflow: scroll" add scroll that can't be scrolled

Tags: html, css, vue.js, scroll, frontend

I want to display the seats in the cinema hall. Sometimes there are a lot of places and I wanted that if the chairs occupied more than 50% of the page, then I had a scroll. I tried to  use "overflow-scroll" but it doesn't work. [photo of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5I0Zu.png)

```
<div class="w-50">
    <div class="border overflow-scroll">
      <div v-for="row in seats" class="d-flex">
        <div v-for="seat in row" :key="seat.id" class="seat"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.seat {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: dodgerblue;
  border: solid black;
}
```

same problem using simple html + css (without vue)

index.html

```css
.seat {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: dodgerblue;
  border: solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div style="width: 50%;">
    <div style="border: solid black; overflow: scroll;">
      <div style="display: flex;">
        <div class="seat"></div>
        <div class="seat"></div>
        <div class="seat"></div>
        <div class="seat"></div>
        <div class="seat"></div>
        <div class="seat"></div>
        <div class="seat"></div>
        <div class="seat"></div>
        <div class="seat"></div>
      </div>
      <div style="display: flex;">
        <div class="seat"></div>
        <div class="seat"></div>
        <div class="seat"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please add more code and explain further

Comment: Hi, to be honest, I don't know what else to add to the previous code. So I did the same example on pure html and css and it works at the same way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `max-width` to limit the viewport. The `overflow: scroll` should be the default anyway. The thing is flexbox will adjust the size of the items (shrink, grow).

Just set the items a `min-width` or use `flex-shrink: 0`.

If you use `flex-wrap: nowrap` together with `flex-direction: column` or shorthand: `flex-flow: column nowrap` for the container (I've added some classes) now, it will grow in width and therefore, since you have set a `max-width` of `50%`, the items will overflow and are scrollable.

```css
.seat {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: dodgerblue;
  border: solid black;
}

.seat-row {
  display: flex;
  flex: column nowrap;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: scroll;
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="seat-row">
      <div class="seat"></div>
      <div class="seat"></div>
      <div class="seat"></div>
      <div class="seat"></div>
      <div class="seat"></div>
      <div class="seat"></div>
      <div class="seat"></div>
      <div class="seat"></div>
      <div class="seat"></div>
      <div class="seat"></div>
      <div class="seat"></div>
      <div class="seat"></div>
      <div class="seat"></div>
      <div class="seat"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="seat-row">
      <div class="seat"></div>
      <div class="seat"></div>
      <div class="seat"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @DmytroKotenko Great that I could help. Would you mind marking the answer as accepted in this case?

Comment: Sry, didn't know that i have such oportunity opportunity :)

Comment: @DmytroKotenko Yep. This is how SO works. Basically "accepted" means it has solved your problem or it has helped you so much so that you could resolve the last bit by yourself (applies if you don't post the whole code and maybe you had another typo or something). Upvotes basically mean: This is of good quality.
Once you resolve a question it shows to other ppl that you are no longer looking for a solution. You can also read here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers